# how to retrieve and handle remote push notification content in iOS app

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-push-notifications

I was trying to fetch remote notification info when the app was not running,so I was told that I can get from :

```
UILocalNotification *localNotification  = [launchOptions 
                   objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey]
```

in method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
               didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

,but still can't get info.

Then I use alertView to show the info on iPhone(launch without Xcode),still can't get the info.

Any other issue would cause this? Please let me know if you have any ideas.

Comment: You can't receive the info when app in closed.It can only be called as you will tap on the alert push message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How to retrieve and handle remote notifications:

## app is running

The `userInfo` in below method already includes the push notification

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
}
```

## app not running

The value for key in launchOptions includes the push notification,under two circumstance:

1.screen is locked,when receive the remote push notification,screen is lighted and user unlock the screen then directly launch the app.

2.user tap on the notification on the drop-down menu to launch the app.
If user tap on the app directly,then the notification will be gone and missed.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
   [launchOptions valueForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] description];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

That key is only in the launch options when the user starts your app from the notification (e.g. taps on it in notification center). Incidentally, I don't think a remote notification would be the class you're using (`UILocalNotification`).

If your app wasn't in the foreground when the device received the push, and the user didn't launch your app from the notification, the notification is gone.  You have to check your own servers to see if you missed anything.

Comment: under this circumstance,how should I do this:

Comment: Like I said, you need to store the info on a server and ask the server what the app missed when it launches.